# Trying to use spanish with pyautogui

Tags: python, translate, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a set of code that listens for a spanish voice and types out the text in spanish. Below is the code.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyautogui 
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey 

r = sr.Recognizer() 
with sr.Microphone() as source:           
  for i in range(3):
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print('Done!')
    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'es-MX')
    print(text)
    pyautogui.typewrite(text)
    hotkey('enter')
```

So, everything works completely fine, but when something is spoken with a letter like an ñ or é or other accents, it will not type them out. Does anyone know how to add a language to this? (I have tried changing my computers keyboard language)

Comment: Is this a problem with pyautogui or speech recognition? Aka, does the `text` variable contain the accented letters?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like pyautogui library doesn't support languages except English,
so you can use pyperclip library to copy text, then use hotkey('ctrl','v')

Check out this:
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/237

Answer (score 0):

Based on @AbdulmajedAhmad's answer, you can paste the text:

```
import pyautogui 
import pyperclip 

def paste_text(text):
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v') # 'command' in macos
```